# Google Chrome Video Download Issue

Tags: google-chrome

I am a google chrome user, almost 90% of the time this browser works best for me, but most oftenly i face an issue and that is while downloading the videos, which are big in size like 400 mb or above, what happens is download proceeds till 80-90% then some error message appears and everything downloaded just gets vanished, this is while downloading videos from MVA, so i wanted to know if it is an issue with the browser or with the server, but i face it almost everytime, according to me its not the server issue.
If anyone can explain.
Yeah and I forgot to specify the error, actually the error is unknown.
[The Image of the error is shown here:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YC2fh.png)
And this happens very time i try to download any big video, and i have even encountered this error while downloading big application, well anything big in size lands to this problem.

Comment: What error message is displayed ? Is there a proxy between you and the remote server ?

Comment: @Gael Yeah forgot to attach the pic of the error I have edited the question you may see the error now, actually its unknown.

Comment: It is about network. Next time you try to download this file do F12 and open 'Network' tab in Chrome. You will see your file as an entry of the list displayed. Click on it you will see more information. But not sure your problem is about Chrome but more about the connection between you and the remote server.

Comment: Can you try with Firefox ?

Comment: @Gael I tried using Firefox and to me it seems like the worst browser, the video is not even starting on that browser, microsoft edge seems to be good browser but downloading dont even start on edge as well.

Comment: OK, it is only happening with big video files ? others big files are working ?

Comment: @Gael Well Not sure about any other big file, haven't downloaded anything like any exe file, i prefer torrent, but for video it's really really frustrating, i tried to download one video in 540p 3-4 times everytime it stops downloading at 130-150mb max, if i download the same video in 360p which is not more than 90-120mb its fine that gets downloaded just fine.

Comment: I think it is due to your internet connection

Comment: @Gael But if I download anything in torrent i never find the speed getting low, i mean it is always between 110-130kbps, let the file be of 100mb, or 1gb.